# Performance : asp.net Cache versus singleton

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, singleton

I have a app that pass through a web service to access data in database.
For performance purpose, I store all apps parameters in cache, otherwise I would call the web service on each page requests.
Some examples of these parameters are the number of search result to display, or wich info should be displayed or not.
The parameters are stored in database because they are edited through a windows management application.
So here comes my question, since these parameters don't have to expire (I store them for a couple of hours), would it be more efficent to store them in a static variable, like a singleton?
What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there'd be a noticeable performance difference in storing your parameters in the `HttpCache` versus a `Singleton` object. Either way, you need to load the parameters when the app starts up.

The advantage of using the `HttpCache` is that it is already built to handle an expiration and refresh, which I assume you would want. If you **never** want to refresh the parameters, then I suppose you could use a Singleton due to the simplicity.

The advantage of building your own custom class is that you can get some static typing for your parameters, since everything you fetch from `HttpCache` will be an `object`. However, it would be trivial to build your own wrapper for the `HttpCache` that will return a strongly typed object.

Comment: These parameters does not have to refresh, except maybe one time a day during the night. In fact, it's way better if they don't refresh while application is in use. But I'm just talking performance here, and what brings the question to me is that the cache need to do a lot more job I think than just storing the data, like handling that said expiration, and retriving the data by his key. But I wonder how significant it can be. Well, I may have the response soon since I'm trying it...

Comment: If the data has to refresh once per day, that still counts. You could just set the HttpCache to refresh those objects at midnight, and then it won't hit the expiration until then. Be careful you don't get stuck in any premature optimization ;-)

Comment: Storing it in the cache for, say, 24 hours, is not an _assurance_ that the data will be there for 24 hours. If the server runs out of memory for whatever reason, the data will be flush. If the pool recycle, the data will be flushed too. I suppose the singleton will be flush too in case of a pool recycle. And we already have a tool to load that data, so that the first client to hit the site will not have to wait for all the parameters to be loaded. There's a lot of them... But that still a good advice about premature optimization ;-) I'm testing it principally to satisfy my own curiosity.

Comment: Yup, the problem is that either way if the pool resets you're going to lose those objects from memory. If we're talking about a lot of data (my impression was it was only a few fields), you could store your data out-of-proc ... basically have a local store on the server that would hold this data and could serve it to your application. Then, as long as this process was running, you'd have access to your parameters.

Comment: After testing in about 25% of the data that is caching and _can_ be coded as singleton, I gained about 10% performance on the test results. But I would still like someone giving me rational explanation about that...